# How to install ATLAS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, configure

I'm trying to install `sextractor` on a dual-booted Windows8.1/Ubuntu14.04 machine with i5 processor.

I'm following [this](http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=722) guide on how to install ATLAS onto Ubuntu.

I always encounter the error:

```
../configure
make: `xconfig' is up to date.
./xconfig -d s /home/user/Programs/atlas/bld/../ -d b /home/user/Programs/atlas/bld 

OS configured as Linux (1)

Assembly configured as GAS_x8664 (2)

Vector ISA Extension configured as  AVXMAC (3,488)

Architecture configured as  Corei3 (28)

Clock rate configured as 3100Mhz

Maximum number of threads configured as  4
Parallel make command configured as '$(MAKE) -j 4'
CPU Throttling apparently enabled!
It appears you have cpu throttling enabled, which makes timings
unreliable and an ATLAS install nonsensical.  Aborting.
See ATLAS/INSTALL.txt for further information
xconfig exited with 1
```

The reported clock rate changes every time I run it!

I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Clock rate probably varies based on the throttling done. As the installer mentions, you have CPU thottling enabled which makes clocking unreliable.  Consider reading `ATLAS/INSTALL.txt` like the error message says.

Comment: So what do I do then?

Comment: Do you really need to build atlas for your platform? is the result likely to be significantly better tuned than the generic pre-built packages from the repository?

Comment: I tried but got `FFTW single precision library files not found at usual locations! Exiting.` when compiling, so I install fftw and it still doesn't work. So I was told to install atlas etc.

Comment: so is your **real** question how to install sextractor?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do yes. I got stuck on ATLAS

Comment: I'm trying to compile ATLAS as well, in order to get true parallelism in numpy when I perform (huge) matrix multiplications, and have a similar problem, event ohugh cpufreq-info reports the governor is 'performance'. Any comments are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is what I posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631796/14-04-i-have-disabled-cpu-throttling-but-installing-atlas-says-cpu-throttlin/643109#643109).

I am a fairly recent Ubuntu user and not a computer expert and I was having exactly the same problem as you. After some struggling, I managed to avoid the message "CPU Throttling apparently enabled!" and got ATLAS 3.10.2 installed.

The first tip I got [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/math-atlas/support-requests/859/#f11d), where it basically says that "The only time ATLAS should detect throttling that isn't occurring is when the processors are fixed to run at a lower speed than their max." My processor was not running at it maximum speed, since I had a BIOS speed limit.

If you have the same problem, look at the maximum frequency allowed in the file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies`. Copy this value to the files `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-3]/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` for each processor. You need to do it as super-user, but before you have to edit the file `/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc` from 0 to 1. More details are given [here](http://blog.patshead.com/2013/04/my-bios-is-limiting-my-cpu-clock-speed.html).

This was still not enough for me and I figured out that I had to edit the files `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-3]/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` to the same value that was used before. After that, I did not get the boring message any more and ATLAS was successfully installed.

I hope that helps!