# 14.04, I have Disabled CPU throttling, but installing Atlas says: "CPU Throttling apparently enabled"

Tags: performance, cpu

My PC is using ubuntu 14.04, and I need install Atlas.

Atlas says: it need to disable CPU throttling, I have done the job to disable it.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{0,1,2,3}/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

But when I was running this command to install Atlas:

```
../configure -b 64 -D c 2400 --prefix=/home/azhen/lib/atlas --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/home/azhen/Downloads/lapack-3.4.1.tgz
```

It says:

```
CPU Throttling apparently enabled!
It appears you have cpu throttling enabled, which makes timings
unreliable and an ATLAS install nonsensical.  Aborting.
See ATLAS/INSTALL.txt for further information
```

Can someone help me take a look?

Comment: cpufreq-info

analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 3.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 3.60 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.20 GHz.

Comment: Before diving down this (potential) rabbit hole, is there a particular reason you can't use the pre-built atlas library from the repository?

Comment: Hi Steeldriver,thank you for your comments, but seems there is not pre-built binary.                                Can I download a prebuilt binary instead of installing from source?

Unfortunately, we lack the manpower to provide prebuild binaries.                         From its help doc: http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#help

Comment: Well, the `libatlas-dev` package (and it's dependency `libatlas-base-dev`) should provide the header files and libraries necessary to build applications using atlas: is that what you need to do? If not, please explain what your end goal is - are you trying to install some other software that depends on atlas?

Comment: I am trying to use http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/, that needs Atlas.

Comment: Well I was able to build a git pull on my 14.04 laptop (without CUDA) following the `cmake` build process described [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation), using `libatlas-dev` from the repository, along with the other dependencies mentioned: I don't think building `atlas` from source should be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I am a fairly recent Ubuntu user and not a computer expert and I was having exactly the same problem as you. After some struggling, I managed to avoid the message "CPU Throttling apparently enabled!" and got ATLAS 3.10.2 installed.

The first tip I got in https://sourceforge.net/p/math-atlas/support-requests/859/#f11d, where it basically says that "The only time ATLAS should detect throttling that isn't occurring is when the processors are fixed to run at a lower speed than their maximum speed." My processor was not running at its maximum speed, since I had a BIOS speed limit.

If you have the same problem, look at the maximum frequency allowed in the file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`.  Copy this value to the files for each processor(/cpu/cpu1, /cpu/cpu2 etc). You need to do it as super-user, but before it takes effect, you have to edit the file `/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc` from 0 to 1. More details are given [here](http://blog.patshead.com/2013/04/my-bios-is-limiting-my-cpu-clock-speed.html).

This was still not enough for me and I figured out that I had to edit the files `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` to the same value that was used before. After that, I did not get the boring message any more and ATLAS was successfully installed!

update: I have just gone through this process again and it seems that the real problem is to have the power scaling driver intel p_state enabled. The procedure above will only work if you disable it first. Follow the instructions in [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html) and replace "enable" by "disable" as explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling).

Answer (score 1):

I followed the Caffe installation guide for ubuntu where it is written that one can install BLAS by

> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

Answer (score 0):

Building ATLAS from source is necessary for Ubuntu 16.04. In addition to what Filipe wrote, I had to disable ACPI in GRUB, which was the root of the throttling issue ([link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI)). I disabled Intel pstate too, since both were installed. I then updated GRUB, which removed all of the CPU throttling files mentioned by Filipe. Here was my process (follow at your own risk):

```
nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text acpi=off intel_pstate=disable"
save
update-grub
reboot
```

The scaling drivers should now be absent, which you can test with this command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
```

Keep in mind that this turns off power and temperature management systems. You may want to turn pstate back on after installing.