# Preventing CPU throttling by kernel / Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, kernel, 64-bit, amd-processor, cpufreq

I'm having an issue with my CPU throttling down. I am on an [A8 Quad Core](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/a8) machine with four 3 GHz processors. The model is a `AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics` About 10 to 15 minutes after booting, the CPU throttles down, as you can see in the attached screenshot.

[image: CPU throttling down...]

I've been to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*` and changed the scaling_max and scaling_min for all four processors. This changes the CPU frequency to 3000 MHz accordingly, but only for a few seconds or minutes at best. Then it just resets back.

In addition to that, I have set the CPU governor to performance and to 3 GHz using the tool on the top bar next to the speaker.

Since I am in Caracas, Venezuela, I am suspecting a heat issue. Though the temperature is staying between 80° to 90° C, I am sure that this is the reason. This would explain why it is working 10 to 15 minutes after booting. Since I have other protection for overheating in place, I have used `sudo apt remove --purge thermald` to remove thermald.

Sadly this has not changed anything. The CPU still won't stick. I am fine with it fluctuating a bit or go down if it is not needed, but the screenshot was made, while the CPU was actually under heavy load, running an application. The result was a frame drop from 40 fps down to 8 fps.

Finally, I have changed grub to disable pstate, as it was mentioned as a solution somewhere here, however like the other steps, this did not change anything at all.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. The issue has occurred with other distros as well however. Mainly I have been using Mint until like 2 months ago and the issue was there as well. The issue however did not occur at all when I was still running Windows. Of course I could just reinstall Windows, but I am quite hesitant about that. I don't like Microsoft and I don't want to be forced to use it.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. This has been plaguing me for months now. Kernel and distro upgrades, file edits and any other attempts I made, have just been to no avail.

Comment: Hi, I have already stated that the temperature is staying between 70 to 80 degrees... sometimes it goes up to 90 but that's it. It is not going any higher. I have obtained the temperatures from psensor.

Comment: On my machines throttling kicks in around 85 degrees. Normal temps are low 50s.

Comment: _BenjB_, Which A8 processor? Need to know to find the TDP. Please click [edit], and let us know. Please don't click Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: I added the requested information...

My machine stays in the higher 70s or lower 80s during normal operation (we have a lot of heat here right now... ) but some intense apps like XP11 or some other games cause the temp to go to 85 or 90 degrees. I have additional protection set for 95 (alarms) and BIOS will shut down the machine at 100.

Comment: Sounds like the thermal paste is not good enough or a broken CPU. The temperature can raise so fast that hardware scales the frequency down to decrease the temperature and this happens fast enough that you cannot monitor the shortest spikes.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Yes! That and hot outside temperature in general seem to be the problem. 35 to 40 degrees C or more is not unusual, so that adds up as well. I have hence looked into particular cooling to fix this issue. I was just surprised, that it occurred in Linux but not in Windows.

Comment: Are you forcing pstate and frequency in Windows, too? In not, the clocks Windows uses are probably lower which cause less heat buildup and less hardware throttling. When you force high clocks the CPU will run at max speed until hardware limit is hit and then you see much bigger slowdown than Windows can ever set the clocks. If you cannot improve cooling, you probably get better overall results with power saving pstate + maybe even thermald.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Nope. I run Windows 10 out of the box. Though I have been using Processing Lasso for some more CPU intense software.

Comment: Ubuntu by default has `thermald` and ondemand CPU frequence policy to reduce heat output. I guess Windows does similar stuff by default. If you turn on `performance` and remove `thermald` you're taking lots of options to reduce heat output away from the system. If your cooling were adequate for that, the overall performance would obviously improve. However, it sounds that your cooling is seriously limited and you need all the support from the software. What kind of CPU frequency you're getting with Windows?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen between 2.8 to 3.0 GHz... On Linux without thermald I am between 2.1 and 2.6 Ghz on performance, depending on what I do. It barely ever goes up to 3 GHz. I am kinda sure it is a cooling problem, especially given the hot climate here. I am just surprised about the fact, that on Windows this seems not to be as much of an issue as on Linux. For example, I run X-Plane 11 on Windows in High Settings and get with new Vulkan Support 45 FPS and low CPU times. Same config on Linux gives about 30 FPS with high CPU times of 0.0600 to 0.1000 while on Windows they are 0.150 to 0.0350.

Comment: @BenjB: it sounds really weird that Windows is able to keep up with high frequency without overheating. Have you re-tested the Windows behavior recently? Sometimes the thermal paste dries up and the system cooling behavior changes drastically. Any GPU intensive app may run different depending on your graphics drivers. Many GPU vendors have poor support for Linux systems.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I did. In fact I went back to dual boot for that reason. Granted, I need ProjectLasso to get full performance for some apps like X-Plane, but performance is significantly better. One thing I have not fully tested though, is if the credit does go indeed completely to ProjectLasso or if Windows maybe offers some better drivers for other Hardware such as GPU, etc. that also take part in this improvement. With the latest XP 11.50 Beta and the introduced Vulkan Support for the simulator, performance has become significantly better on Linux. But it also did on Windows as well.

Comment: I'd guess the reason is that AMD Linux GPU driver is worse than the Windows counterpart. On AMD APU CPU both live inside the CPU and if GPU overheats because of GPU driver issue, the whole system performance will be reduced because clocks are forced lower. Are you using open source drivers or AMD proprietary GPU driver? For official documentation, see https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635

Comment: For AMD proprietary drivers, see https://www.amd.com/en/support (in your case, you want to start with "Processors with graphics" and "AMD A-Series"). It looks like AMD has already dropped support for your GPU, though.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen The GPU should not be much of an issue. I barely use the onboard GPU, though its connected to my second screen. The main GPU is a NVidia 1050 Ti which is taking most of the load for applications, etc. I have also recently (yesterday) upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I will have to see if that changes anything.